# Media query not working properly for defined screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am currently working on a website and for making it responsive, I inspect it (in Google Chrome) and then change screen resolution and accordingly edit media queries.

The problem I am facing is, for ex. I wrote a media query for 1366x768 (according to the inspect and resolution change method), it works fine but when I actually view it on a device with 1366x768 resolution it differs. But if in that new device I inspect and make the screen resolution 1366x768 then it shows my edits.
Why is this happening? How can I make edits for actual devices?

Comment: How about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40337658/4636715

Comment: That also didn't work.

Comment: have you add media query by javascropt or jquery?

Comment: Media queries in CSS

Comment: What is your media query?

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1367px)

Comment: show your code with issue..

Comment: I can't post the code, but for instance, I have an icon on the top-right corner(inside) of a div, according to inspect's view it needed to be arranged at top: -9px for screen resolution 1366x768. But when I open that in the device which has this resolution then it seems that it should have been at top: -1px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to develop your website as a responsive one is using "rem" instead of px, for almost everything as in for font sizes, padding, etc. And change the root font size for different media queries, and voila it's much easier!

I learned this the hard way but worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added responsive meta tag in your html?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yes I have added that.

Comment: Then better you can do by editing in real device by following this.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: But for that I'll require every resolution's devices.