# How to properly Down-sampling HTML Canvas for good looking images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

**Introduction**

I'm trying to deal with blurry visuals on my canvas animation. The blurriness is especially prevalent on mobile-devices, retina and high-dpi (dots-per-inch) screens.

I'm looking for a way to ensure the pixels that are drawn using the canvas look their best on low-dpi screens and high-dpi screens. As a solution to this problem I red multiple articles about canvas-down-scaling and followed this tutorial:

https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/canvas_high_dpi_retina.htm

**Integrating down-scaling in the project**

The project in which I want to implement down-scaling can be found below and consists of a few important features:

- There is a (big) main canvas. (Performance optimization)
- There are multiple (pre-rendered) smaller canvasses that are used to draw and load a image into. (Performance optimization)
- The canvas is animated. (In the code snippet, there is no visible animation but the animation function is intergrated.)

**Question**

What im trying to achieve: The problem I'm facing seems quite simple. When the website (with the canvas) is opened on a mobile device (eg. an Iphone, with more pixels per inch then a regular desktop). The images appear more blurry. What I'm actually trying to achieve is to remove this blurriness from the images. I red [this](https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/canvas_high_dpi_retina.htm) and it stated that blurriness can be removed by downsampling. I tried to incorporate this technique in the code provided, but it did not work completely. The images just became larger and I was unable to scale the images back to the original size. snippet it is not implemented correctly, the output is still blurry. What did I do wrong and how am I able to fix this issue?

**Explanation of the code snippet**

The variable `devicePixelRatio` is set to `2` to simulate a high-dpi phone screen, low-dpi screens have a `devicePixelRatio` of 1.
Multiple pre-rendered canvasses generated is the function `spawn` is the snippet there are 5 different canvasses, but on the production environment there are 10's.

*If there are any pieces of information missing or questions about this post, please let me know. Thanks a lot!*

**Code Snippet**

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d' );
var circles = [];

//Simulate Retina screen = 2, Normal screen = 1
let devicePixelRatio = 2


function mainCanvasPixelRatio() {
    // get current size of the canvas
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    // increase the actual size of our canvas
    canvas.width = rect.width * devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.height = rect.height * devicePixelRatio;

    // ensure all drawing operations are scaled
    c.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

    // scale everything down using CSS
    canvas.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
}

// Initial Spawn
function spawn() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        //Set Radius
        let radius = parseInt(i*30);

        //Give position
        let x = Math.round((canvas.width/devicePixelRatio) / 2);
        let y = Math.round((canvas.height /devicePixelRatio) / 2);

        //Begin Prerender canvas
        let PreRenderCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const tmp = PreRenderCanvas.getContext("2d");

        //Set PreRenderCanvas width and height
        let PreRenderCanvasWidth = ((radius*2)*1.5)+1;
        let PreRenderCanvasHeight =  ((radius*2)*1.5)+1;


        //Increase the actual size of PreRenderCanvas
        PreRenderCanvas.width = PreRenderCanvasWidth * devicePixelRatio;
        PreRenderCanvas.height = PreRenderCanvasHeight * devicePixelRatio;

        //Scale PreRenderCanvas down using CSS
        PreRenderCanvas.style.width = PreRenderCanvasWidth + 'px';
        PreRenderCanvas.style.height = PreRenderCanvasHeight + 'px';

        //Ensure PreRenderCanvas drawing operations are scaled
        tmp.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

        //Init image
        const image=  new Image();

        //Get center of PreRenderCanvas
        let m_canvasCenterX = (PreRenderCanvas.width/devicePixelRatio) * .5;
        let m_canvasCenterY =  (PreRenderCanvas.height/devicePixelRatio) * .5;

        //Draw red circle on PreRenderCanvas
        tmp.strokeStyle = "red";
        tmp.beginPath();
        tmp.arc((m_canvasCenterX), (m_canvasCenterY), ((PreRenderCanvas.width/devicePixelRatio)/3) , 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        tmp.lineWidth = 2;
        tmp.stroke();
        tmp.restore();
        tmp.closePath()

        //Set Image
        image .src=  "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3"

        //Get padding
        let paddingX = (PreRenderCanvas.width/devicePixelRatio)/5;
        let paddingY = (PreRenderCanvas.height/devicePixelRatio)/5;

        //Load image
        image.onload = function () {
            tmp.beginPath()
            tmp.drawImage(image, paddingX,paddingY, (PreRenderCanvas.width/devicePixelRatio)-(paddingX*2),(PreRenderCanvas.height/devicePixelRatio)-(paddingY*2));
            tmp.closePath()
        }

        let circle = new Circle(x, y, c ,PreRenderCanvas);

        circles.push(circle)
    }
}



// Circle parameters
function Circle(x, y, c ,m_canvas) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.c = c;
    this.m_canvas = m_canvas;
}

//Draw circle on canvas
Circle.prototype = {
    //Draw circle on canvas
    draw: function () {
        this.c.drawImage( this.m_canvas, (this.x - (this.m_canvas.width)/2), (this.y - this.m_canvas.height/2));
    }
};

// Animate
function animate() {
    //Clear canvas each time
    c.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width /devicePixelRatio), (canvas.height /devicePixelRatio));

    //Draw in reverse for info overlap
    circles.slice().reverse().forEach(function( circle ) {
        circle.draw();
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

mainCanvasPixelRatio()
spawn()
animate()
```

```css
#mainCanvas {
     background:blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>

<br>
```

Comment: The image you're loading is 512x512. Yet, neither of your images are shown at this size, ergo - they're each downsized. What actually are you trying to achieve? I ask because both images look like a poor scaling of the original - they're each blurry in different ways. Take the white, rounded corners for instance - the top image does a much better job of representing the corner using antialiasing, than the second does. The second has an obvious squareness to it...

Comment: @enhzflep  Thank you for your comment. The problem I'm facing seems quite simple. When the website (with the canvas) is opened on a mobile device (eg. an Iphone, with more pixels per inch then a regular desktop). The images appear more blurry. What I'm actually trying to achieve is to remove this blurriness from the images. I red that the blurriness can be removed by downsampling. I tried to incorporate this technique in the code provided, but it did not work completely. The images just became larger and I was unable to scale the images back to the original size.

Comment: Ahhhh! I see. After reading your comment (I should have picked it up from the question :oops:) my immediate thought was to CSS Media Queries. Rather than have the device scale the image with some JS, I'd consider using CSS to load images of different resolutions, such that the image is shown at 100%. Perhaps not useful to you though, since you're talking about animations rather than static images. First link (since it talks about viewport scaling) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337658/how-to-use-media-query-for-high-resolution-devices and (see next comment)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for similar info presented differently.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you for the suggestion, In my case I really want to use devicePixelRatio this automatically detects the screen pixel ration on the device itself. I think it is more modern and more accurate compared to media queries. I like i said before I tried to implement this but the scaling back doesnt work. Do you have any idea what I did wrong or how I could improve?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277"
```

src="pic_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

```
<p>Canvas:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297"
```

style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

```
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");
```

ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};

```
</script>

</body>
```